# Move text cursor with compose key sequence

Tags: x11, compose-key, caret-cursor

I was wondering if it is possible in my `.Xcompose` file to have a compose sequence that also moves the cursor.

For example, if I have

```
<Multi_key> <c> <n> <w> : "<code><nowiki></nowiki></code>"
```

Is it possible to make it so that I can choose where the text cursor will be? In this example, it should be like

```
<code><nowiki>CURSOR HERE</nowiki></code>
```

If it's not possible via a compose key, is there any other way to do so?

Comment: in terminal setting you could just add "\033[D" many times afterwards but otherwise ig you need something else than .Xcompose